# How do I extract data from Data Layer via Google Tag Manager/Analytics API

Tags: python, rest, google-api, etl, google-tag-manager

Data Layer Has been deployed to my website. However, I'm struggling to find a way to extract the data which is held in Google Tag Manager, for it to be used in PowerBI, etc

Preferably, I would like to use python to create this ETL pipeline. Can you give me a direction to look into?

The general Google Tag Manager seems to be used for configuring the data layers/variable/accounts etc. With no clear way to extract the data

Answer (score 2):

Google Tag Manager ***doesnot*** holds the data. It's a `tag manager`, which means it contains Javascript codes known as `tags` to send the data to Google Analytics. [Datalayer](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web/datalayer) is the JS object that exists on your web platform and contains metadata that you push from backend/frontend.

The data is actually collected in `Google Analytics`.

So, if you want to pull the data from `Google Analytics`, you have two options

1. ***If you are a GA360 premium customer:*** you can use `Big Query` data dump to export that data from BQ to the internal Data warehouse. You can unflatten the structure of the data(GA3) and get the pipeline started. You can also use a direct BQ [connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-bigquery) in Power BI
2. ***If you use GA free( universal analytics***) - Your only hope is to use GA API to pull the data in the warehouse.

***If you use GA4*** - then GA4 has Big Query connection for the free version as well, you can use BQ to pull the data or connect BQ as a [connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-bigquery) in Power BI

Answer (score 0):

Great Question.

Please refer to the documentation on
https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web/datalayer